# using script tags in react gives a error "Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am transforming my website to react site but the script tags inside do not work. It just says **unexpected token**. Here's the code.

```
 <div className="people">
How many of you shall we expect?
<br />
<select id="noofpeople">
<option>1 person</option>
<script>
  var count = 2;
  while(count<21){
    document.write("<option>"+count+" people"+"</option>");
    count++;
  }

</script>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan NO, I am a noob and those examples were too complicated for me.

Comment: Are you returning the code in render method that you showed?

Comment: Are you working with a functional component or just a class component?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan Yeah I am using render method

Comment: @zonecc its a class component

Comment: Plus, you could just create a method/function to do that for you and call it. React is javascript by itself. What you are trying to do is like add javascript in javascript.

Comment: cool @RoshanParajuli then let me give you a way I think should be simple to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to Achieve the result you want since you can't return a script in JSX you could try something like.

```
import React from 'react';

class PrintOptions extends React.Component{

render() {
   let count = 2;
   const addOptions = () => {
     while (count < 21) {
        document.write("<option>" + count + " people" + "</option>");
        count ++;
     }
   }

   return(
       <div> 
            {addOptions()} 
       </div<
   )}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I would suggest this.
```

```html
 class GetSelection extends React.Component {
 
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChange(event) {
this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
  
handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your selections is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  


render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          How many of you shall we expect?
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="1">1 person</option>
            <option value="2">2 person</option>
            <option value="3">3 person</option>
           
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cann't return a `script` tag in `JSX`. You need to do such things in component lifecycle methods. Here is an example for you.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Don't call this.setState() here!
    this.state = { options: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    var count = 2;
    let newOptions = [];
    while(count<21){
      newOptions.push(`${count} People`);
    }
    this.setState({ options: newOptions });
  }

  render(){
    return (<div className="people">
       How many of you shall we expect?
       <br />
       <select id="noofpeople">
          <option>1 person</option>
          {this.state.options.map((option, index) => {
             return <option key={index}>{option}</option>
          })}
       </select>
     </div>)
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Hope this works for you.